# MySql Query only returning some information

Tags: mysql, datetimepicker

I have VB.net Winforms program that saves customer quote entries to a MySql database. Each entry has several fields and one of those is "NewEntryDate". This is to show when the entries were first made. I need to call the entries between two dates but when I run the following query it returns **all** the entries that qualify under the select area of the statement, not only the entries between the two dates.

The user selects the two dates from two Datetimepickers.

```
query = "select NewEntryDate,TimeOfEntry,QuoteNumber,QuoteStatus,
                ClientName, POCTel,POCEmail 
        from database.db_table 
        where QuoteStatus= 'Quote Sold' 
        OR QuoteStatus= 'Quote Lost' 
        AND NewEntryDate BETWEEN str_to_date('" & DateTimePicker7.Text & "','%Y-%m-%d') 
        AND str_to_date('" & DateTimePicker10.Text & "','%Y-%m-%d') 
        order by NewEntryDate DESC, TimeOfEntry DESC"
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: The astute use of parentheses is required.

Comment: If you can read it, then maybe you can debug it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` has precedence over `OR`, so you need parentheses around this expression:

```
(QuoteStatus= 'Quote Sold' OR QuoteStatus= 'Quote Lost')
```

Alternatively, you can use the `IN` operator instead of `OR`:

```
QuoteStatus IN ('Quote Sold', 'Quote Lost')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like a pizza or burger and fries?

Is the above statement equivalent to:

Would you like a pizza or (burger and fries)?

Or

Would you like a (pizza or burger) and fries?